# Two temporary, simultaneous student visas to two different countries

Tags: visas, schengen, canada, denmark

I have perhaps a very particular question-
I'm thinking about research plans for a master's degree. I am a US citizen and plan to attend a Canadian university for my MA, but was hoping to apply for a 5 or 10-month research/study period in Denmark (my topic of research is relevant for separate but related reasons to both countries, and so it would be beneficial to work within both Canadian and Danish institutions).

So, I would require one 2-year temporary student permit from Canada from for example 1.9.2014 - 31.8.2016, and one 5 or 10-month temporary student and/or research permit from Denmark from 1.8.2015 - 31.12.2015 or 1.8.2015 - 31.5.2016. Is this possible? I would not be able to cut short the Canadian permit as I would still be enrolled in a Canadian university and would need to return in the winter and summer for presentations etc.

If anyone has a similar experience with requiring two residence permits to separate countries where the time periods overlap, related to student permits or not, I would greatly appreciate some insight. I have lived in Norway for the last four years and have never met anyone who has had the same problem (I am thinking about this far in advance, and of course would ask the relevant departments for each country)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think this would be a problem?  Canada and Denmark are separate countries with completely separate immigration and visa systems, each application will be judged on its own merits and will have no impact on the other.  If anything, having the visa for Canada will *increase* your odds of being granted the Denmark (Schengen) permit, since it's effectively proof that you'll return when your research is done.